# azure failed to add extension to virtual machine

Tags: azure, virtual

I am trying to add the Antimalware extension to a virtual machine for protection but when i try to add the extension in the Azure portal i get the following error:

Failed to add extension to virtual machine. The virtual machine request is invalid The specified source image is a user image. The image must be a platform image.

I have installed the VMAgent.

As extra information i have tried using powershell commands to install the extension by using the following commands and getting the respective responses:

**$vm = Get-AzureVM –ServiceName "MyServiceName" –Name "MyVMName"**

VERBOSE: ... - completed operation: Get Deployment*

**Set-AzureVMExtension -Publisher Microsoft.Azure.Security -ExtensionName IaaSAntimalware -Version 1.* -VM $vm.VM**

WARNING: The resource extension reference list is null or empty

AvailabilitySetName               :
ConfigurationSets                 : {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.Model.NetworkConfigurationSet}
DataVirtualHardDisks              : {"MyVMName"}
Label                             :
OSVirtualHardDisk                 : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.Model.OSVirtualHardDisk
RoleName                          : "MyVMName"
RoleSize                          : Large
RoleType                          : PersistentVMRole
WinRMCertificate                  :
X509Certificates                  :
NoExportPrivateKey                : False
NoRDPEndpoint                     : False
NoSSHEndpoint                     : False
DefaultWinRmCertificateThumbprint : F4CF28C735C5E557C7B47742E4F16A08959272F1
ProvisionGuestAgent               :
ResourceExtensionReferences       : {IaaSAntimalware}
DataVirtualHardDisksToBeDeleted   :

**Update-AzureVM -Name "MyServiceName" -ServiceName "MyVMName" -VM $vm.VM**

VERBOSE: 11:15:10 - Completed Operation: Get Deployment
VERBOSE: 11:15:10 - Begin Operation: Update-AzureVM
VERBOSE: 11:15:42 - Completed Operation: Update-AzureVM

OperationDescription                    OperationId                             OperationStatus
--------------------                    -----------                             ---------------
Update-AzureVM                          387b77a2-c8fc-233a-913d-cd364c855429    Succeeded

After i run the commands i check and VMAgent is installed on the VM but no extension.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The cause might be your first line
$vm = Get-AzureVM –ServiceName "MyServiceName" –Name "MyVMName"

- When -servicename and -name are not specified, Get-AzureVM returns no VM object
- Set-AzureVMextension only works with -VM input

Try this:

https://gist.github.com/andreaswasita/428fc5519b0ddac76b01

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this warning is due to the Azure Guest agent not being deployed on the VM, not running on the VM, or being out-of-date. If the VM doesn't have a healthy (and current) guest agent, you won't be able to deploy extensions.

You can check the guest agent status with:

```
$vm.GuestAgentStatus
```

You'd be looking for a "Status" of "Ready"; anything else and the extension is likely to fail. Extending Klaad's code then...

```
# Azure Cloud Service and Azure VM Name 
$service= Read-Host -Prompt 'Azure Cloud Service:' 
$name = Read-Host -Prompt 'Azure VM:' 

# Get the Cloud Service and Azure VM 
$vm = Get-AzureVM –ServiceName $service –Name $name 

# Check for health of the agent
If ($vm.GuestAgentStatus.Status -ne "Ready") {
    Write-Error "The VM agent appears to not be installed or is in an unhealthy state."
}
Else {
    # Add Microsoft Antimalware Agent to the Azure VM 
    Set-AzureVMExtension -Publisher Microsoft.Azure.Security -ExtensionName IaaSAntimalware -Version 1.* -VM $vm.VM 

     # Update the Azure VM and install the Antimalware Agent 
    Update-AzureVM -Name $name -ServiceName $service -VM $vm.VM 
}
```

To check if the agent is there, you can look for the following three processes on the server:

```
WaAppAgent.exe
WindowsAzureGuestAgent.exe
WindowsAzureTelemetryService.exe
```

You can download the agent from [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=394789) (current version at time of edit is 2.6.1198.718).

Installation requires two steps (Source: [Zach Millis](https://blog.imason.com/manually-installing-the-azure-guest-agent-on-virtual-machines/)):

1. Install the agent. This requires you to run PowerShell as an Administrator and execute the installer from within the PowerShell prompt. (Do not run directly)
2. Update Azure so it knows about the agent. This requires the following code to be executed:

Code:

```
# Azure Cloud Service and Azure VM Name
$service= Read-Host -Prompt 'Azure Cloud Service:' 
$name = Read-Host -Prompt 'Azure VM:' 

# Get the Cloud Service and Azure VM 
$vm = Get-AzureVM –ServiceName $service –Name $name 

# Provision the guest agent so Azure knows about it
$vm.VM.ProvisionGuestAgent = $TRUE

# Update the Azure VM and install the Antimalware Agent 
$vm | Update-AzureVM

# Refresh the connection to the VM to get the new status
$vm = Get-AzureVM –ServiceName $service –Name $name 

# Check status - should now be "Ready"
$vm.GuestAgentStatus
```

That should be it.